# Processing Return key in wxGrid class

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

Recently I'm using python 2.7 and wx2.8 as a base of my application. Since that time I have problems in processing of Return key in my app. I have this error only on windows - in linux it works fine. 
All keys except Return/Numpad Return are processed. 
I put wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER| wx.WANTS_CHARS style on my Frame and my Grid. 
I tried ON KEY DOWN and ON CHAR HOOK events- on frame and grid and grid renderer.
My Return key is lost somewhere. 
Tried solutions from :
[What does wxWidgets' EVT_CHAR_HOOK do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876966/what-does-wxwidgets-evt-char-hook-do)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/1RaaGxu62q4 (this was like perfect description of my problem but failed)

http://osdir.com/ml/python.wxpython/2004-03/msg00261.html

Any ideas, pls?

Regards 
Mike

Comment: When writing an answer recently ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416650/wxpython-binding-wx-evt-char-hook-disables-textctrl-backspace/20419894#20419894 ), I have noticed that I had to bind Return to `wx.EVT_KEY_UP`. I am still not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a few inconsistencies between the wxPython versions. Try following example:

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self.panel)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(3, 3)
        self.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)
        self.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyUp)
        self.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.OnChar)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.grid, 1)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)  
        self.Show()

    # You may or may not want to add e.Skip() to your RETURN key handling.
    # If you do not call e.Skip(), the event is not propagated to the widget.
    # Depends on your app logic if that is something you want or not.

    def OnKeyDown(self, e):      
        # Python 2.7, wxPython 2.8 - Works, but more like EVT_CHAR_HOOK
        # Python 3.3, wxPython Phoenix - Never shows up
        code = e.GetKeyCode()
        if code in [wx.WXK_RETURN, wx.WXK_NUMPAD_ENTER]:
            print("Return key down")
        else:
            e.Skip() 

    def OnKeyUp(self, e):
        code = e.GetKeyCode()
        if code in [wx.WXK_RETURN, wx.WXK_NUMPAD_ENTER]:
            print("Return key up")
        else:
            e.Skip() 

    def OnChar(self, e):
        # Python 2.7, wxPython 2.8 - Never shows up
        # Python 3.3, wxPython Phoenix - Works
        code = e.GetKeyCode()
        if code in [wx.WXK_RETURN, wx.WXK_NUMPAD_ENTER]:
            print("Return key char")
        else:
            e.Skip() 


app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thaks, it's good direction. I resolved my problem by using CharHook event on my Window class, not only grid. It receives return key. I can manually run OnGridKeyDown event if it's wx2.8. On lower versions i just event.Skip().